# filter the array of object on the basis of key name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I Have array of object like below

```js
 employees = [
    {name: "Tony Stark", department: "IT"},

    {name: "Peter Parker", department: "Pizza Delivery"},


    {name: "Bruce Wayne", department: "IT"},

    {name: "Clark Kent", department: "Editing"}
];
```

and I want to filter array of object like

```js
 employees = [
    {name: "Tony Stark"},

    {name: "Peter Parker"},


    {name: "Bruce Wayne"},

    {name: "Clark Kent"}
];
```

Comment: I think you want to `map` the array, rather than filtering it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Would you please share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `map()`

```js
const employees = [
  { name: "Tony Stark", department: "IT" },
  { name: "Peter Parker", department: "Pizza Delivery" },
  { name: "Bruce Wayne", department: "IT" },
  { name: "Clark Kent", department: "Editing" }
];

const result = employees.map(({ name }) => ({ name }));

console.log(result);
```

```js
const employees = [
  { name: "Tony Stark", department: "IT" },
  { name: "Peter Parker", department: "Pizza Delivery" },
  { name: "Bruce Wayne", department: "IT" },
  { name: "Clark Kent", department: "Editing" }
];

const result = employees.map((employee) => { 
  return { 
    name: employee.name 
  }
});

console.log(result);
```